# before_filter to set common instance variable (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it a common practice to do a filter like this:

```
before_filter :get_clients, :only => [:new, :edit, :create, :update]
...
def get_clients
      @clients = Client.accessible_by(current_ability)
end
```

My form needs access to @clients, so I setup the variable @clients with a before filter instead of doing it in every method. Does this make sense?

Comment: It's common , dry and clean (even if apparently not restful).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend building a memoized helper instead:

```
def current_clients
  @current_clients ||= Client.accessible_by(current_ability)
end
helper :current_clients
```

This will work just as well as a before-filter, but won't be run unless you need to actually load the client list for a form/view.  You're getting lazy loading of this resource.  The responsibility for knowing how to load the list of clients still remains with the controller.

Comment: Just tried the suggestion, the problem is current_ability only seems to be available from the controller. (I am using cancan)

Comment: The code block I was pasting should go within the controller.  You're not able to access your can-can helpers there?

Comment: Out of curiosity does this method of including a helper do anything in the way of testing?  I have a similar authorization method in app controller which is called in all of my controllers with a before filter.  When testing I comment this out so my test code can run through my code without being redirected to a login screen.

Comment: @Rick - You're probably better off stubbing a logged in user than commenting out code to test.  For example, if you have a current_user method that looks up the authenticated user from the session, you could just stub that out to your test user.

Comment: @Rick - but yes, making functions/helpers like this makes it easier to test and easier to stub out values when you're isolating parts of the system.